# CoreData unique constraints disappears in Xcode

Tags: xcode, core-data, unique-constraint

## What I want to do:

Add a unique constraint on the attribute `photoID` in the entity `PhotoUpload`.

## Problem:

I tap on constraints and add `photoID`.

When I navigate to a different file and come back to the `xcdatamodeld` file, the constraint is not present. It is automatically removed.

And so the unique constraint is not working.

## What I have done so far:

- I have tried deleting the `xcdatamodeld` file and re-created it, but the same problem persists.

## Screenshot:

[image]

## Versions:

Xcode - 7.3.1

Comment: I believe this to be a bug in Xcode.  To overcome it, change another element of the model at the same time as adding the uniqueness constraint.  Save the model.  Then change the other element back and save again.  See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35682163/3985749) for example.

Comment: Thanks a million, spent hours on this ! Nasty bag indeed. If you can post it as an answer I can mark it as answered for the benefit of others

Comment: Thanks - answer added.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe this to be a bug in Xcode. If you change the model to add (or amend or remove) a constraint, the underlying model file is not updated, even though the screen shows the changes correctly.  To overcome it, change another element of the model at the same time as adding the uniqueness constraint. Save the model. Then change the other element back and save again.