# Core data uniquing and filter using predicate

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I designed a simple application with core data having two entities
owner
cars

owner can have multiple cars but the car is connected to one owner.Hence, each owner has his own car even though if its the same.

Now, i have two issues here

1. I read that unique constraints can be added to have unique owners. Hence, i made the username of owner as a constraint. I should've got an error when i ran the app but i did not. There are duplicate owners. What is wrong here?
2. I have a search bar to filter cars where i use predicate to filter as "carName contains[cd] %@" and it works fine but if i do the same or other ways using "==" or "like", it is crashing stating error "keypath Kaushik not found in entity". The predicate i gave was "name == kaushik".Why is it taking RHS? What is wrong here?

FYI: I am trying all of this today.Hence, Swift and iOS are all latest versions.

let owner = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "Owner", into: objectContext) as? Owner

```
    Owner?.name="Kaushik"
    Owner?.address="10,downing street"
    Owner?.mobile=0123456789
    Owner?.landline= 0123456789
    lender?.userName="KV"

    do
    {
        try objectContext.save()

    }catch
    {
        print("error")
    }
```

above is the code to add a owner

[image: unique constraint]

Can someone please clarify my doubts
Thank you

Comment: Please *edit your question* to show the relevant code

Comment: You should be able to use `NSPredicate(format: "carName == \"Kaushik\"")` or `NSPredicate(format: "carName ==  %@", "Kaushik")`.

Comment: Regarding the uniqueness constraint, check if [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38501757/3985749) helps.

Comment: thanks Rob it worked..but why can't i give the name directly? Why require double quotes?

Comment: yeah @pbasf it worked. .. i changed an attribute type and back..It works fine now thanks

Comment: You need the quotes because it's a string literal. Without quotes, it thinks it's referring to a property of the object.

Comment: oh ok ..thank you @Rob