# Swift Core Data constraints don't seem to be working

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, constraints, unique-constraint

I am having a problem with constraints in Core Data and would be grateful for any help.  I have the following two lines in the AppDelegate.

```
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate  
    let context = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
```

In the func that is the save func I have these two lines.

```
    context.mergePolicy = NSMergeByPropertyStoreTrumpMergePolicy
    appDelegate.saveContext()
```

At the moment I am just trying to get my head around Core Data and the idea for what I want to happen is this:
I have a screen where there is a text field and two buttons ( one button is "Save Data" and the other is "Display Data").  I have a second screen holding a TableView where the data is to be displayed.  The constraint has been set in the data model screen.  On a clean install on the simulator, say for example I enter Fred in the text field and click the save button....then click the display button.  No problem the name Fred is displayed.  Everything is working fine.  Back to the text field and type in Fred again (according to the NSMergeByPropertyStoreTrumpMergePolicy) the second one shouldn't be displayed correct?  In fact the second is displayed but the 3rd, 4th, 5th and so on are not. If I enter Fred then Ben and then Fred and Ben I will have displayed Fred twice and Ben once.  Any help would be great.

Comment: Are you trying to use the merge policy to prevent saving entities with the same name?

Comment: @Magnas5  Yes is the short answer

Comment: If you are creating a new managedObject each time you click the Save button then the merge policy will not have any effect. The policy only looks for versions of the same object, one in the store and one external, not different objects with the same attribute value, e.g. name. This wouldn't explain the missing objects when you slick save multiple times however - it's hard to say without seeing some of your code.

Comment: @Magnas thanks for the comment. At the moment I am away for my computer but later on today I will add a comment with the save function ..... is that all you need to see?

Comment: Would also be useful to see how you are populating your tableView.

Comment: @Magnas not a problem

Comment: Are you sure the constraints have actually been applied?  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38501757/3985749).  There is a bug in xcode which means the constraints do not get applied.

Comment: @pbasfd thanks for the comment... I tried what you lay out in the answer with no luck I am afraid.

Comment: @Magnas func fetchData(){
    
        do {
            data = try context.fetch(Job.fetchRequest())
            data2 = try context.fetch(Hours_Date.fetchRequest())
            for i in 0..<data.count{
                //this line will print to the console
                print("Job Name: \(data[i].jobName!) \nDate: \(data2[i].date!) worked \(data2[i].hours) hours")
                
            }
        }
        catch{
            //Look after error
        }
    }